# Вычисление сложного процента в swift?

Tags: swift

Остров Манхэттен был приобретен поселенцами за $24 в 1826 г. Каково было бы в настоящее время состояние их счета, если бы эти 24 доллара были помещены тогда в банк под 6% годового дохода?

```
func priceOfIceland(price: Double, years: Double, yearPercent: Double) -> Double {
    let result = pow(price*(1 + yearPercent/100),years)
    print(result)
    return result
}
```

Что я не так пишу? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Вопрос не имеет конкретного вопроса, сообщения об ошибках и прочего. Если это вопрос математики - этот вопрос должен быть перенесён в соответствующую ветку

Comment: Что выводится? Что должно выводиться? На вход точно верные аргументы поступают?

Comment: В консоли выводится результат - 4.6807856471934326e+272
А на входе вот такие аргументы -  priceOfIceland(price: 24.0, years: 194.0, yearPercent: 6.0)

Comment: Добавьте информацию  о результате который получается в вопрос. Так будет проще его понимать сразу, и не перечитывать коментарии.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно вот так:

```
let result = price * pow((1 + yearPercent/100), years)
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!